# Function coincides with a function of bounded variation almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, bounded-variation

## Problem

Suppose $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ satisfies that there exists $A\ge0$ such that
$$\int_{\mathbb R}\lvert f(x+h)-f(x)\rvert dx\le A\lvert h\rvert$$
for all $h\in\mathbb R$. We need to show that $f$ coincides with some function of bounded variation on $\mathbb R$, i.e., there exists $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, such that $g$ is of bounded variation on $\mathbb R$, and $f=g$ a.e.

## Discussion

Conversely, if $f$ is of bounded variation, then $f$ could be written as the difference of two bounded increasing functions, and then the absolute value could be *expanded* and the approximation is somewhat easier. However, I need to prove the converse proposition, which seems tough to me.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: The last sentence in your question appears to b incomplete.

Comment: All you need to do is

Comment: @Thomas Edited. The network got stuck, and I even LOST a post. Now I need to repost it.

Comment: @user104254 I saw them in Stein's book, but apparently not familiar. It seems that the condition is somewhat different (though the key idea is Dirac $\delta$-shaped functions) and it claims that the convolutions converges pointwisely to the original function at Lebesgue points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a measurable function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$, denote
$$T:\Bbb R\to [0,+\infty]:\quad h\mapsto \int_{\Bbb R}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx. \tag{1}$$
Your assumption on $f$ is simply
$$T(h)\le A|h|,\quad \forall~h\in\Bbb R. \tag{2}$$
When $f$ is locally integrable, i.e. integrable on every compact set, by Lebesgue differentiation theorem,

$$F:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C,\quad x\mapsto \int_0^x f(t)dt \tag{3}$$
is well defined, 
$$\quad E:=\{x\in\Bbb R: F'(x)\text { exists}\} \tag{4}$$ 
is of full measure and $F'=f$ a.e. .  Moreover, denote the total variation of $F'$ on $E$ by ${\rm V}$, i.e. 
$$V:=\sup\big\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F'(x_i)-F'(x_{i-1})|: x_0,x_1,\cdots, x_n\in E,\  x_0<x_1<\cdots <x_n\big\}. \tag{5}$$
We claim that for every local integrable function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$, 
$$V\le \liminf_{h\to 0}\frac{T(h)}{|h|}. \tag{6}$$
Once $(6)$ is proved, from $(2)$ we know that $F'$ is of bounded variation on $E$. To complete the proof, without of loss of generality, we may suppose that $f$ is real valued(otherwise, consider real part and imaginary part separately). Then $F'$ is real valued and of bounded variation on $E$. By imitation the argument for functions of bounded variation on an interval, we can see that there are bounded increasing functions $f_\pm: E\to \Bbb R$, such that $F'=f_+-f_-$ on $E$.  Extend $f_\pm$ to bounded increasing functions on $\Bbb R$, still denoted by $f_\pm$. As a result, for $g:=f_+-f_-$, $g$ is of bounded variation on $\Bbb R$.  Since $E$ is of full measure in $\Bbb R$, $g=F'=f$ a.e. . Therefore, it suffices to prove $(6)$.

---

**Proof of $(6)$:**

Given $h\ne 0$ and points $x_0<\cdots < x_n$ in $E$,
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \sum_{i=1}^n\left|\frac{F(x_i+h)-F(x_i)}{h}-\frac{F(x_{i-1}+h)-F(x_{i-1})}{h}\right| \\
&=& \frac{1}{|h|}\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i}\left(f(x+h)-f(x)\right)dx \right| \\
&\le& \frac{1}{|h|}\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i}|f(x+h)-f(x)|dx \\
&\le& \frac{T(h)}{|h|} .
\end{eqnarray}
Letting $h\to 0$ first and then taking supremum for $x_0<\cdots < x_n$ in $E$, $(6)$ follows. $\quad\square$

---

**Remark:** With some additional work, it can be shown that:

1. Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$ be measurable. If $(2)$ holds for some $A>0$, then $f$ is locally integrable.
2. Now suppose $f$ is locally integrable, so $(3)$, $(4)$ and $(5)$ are well defined. Define
   $$\mathscr F:=\{g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C \mid g=f \text{ a.e.} \},\tag{7}$$
   and for every $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$, denote its total variation on $\Bbb R$ by ${\rm Var}(g)$. Then we have:
   $$V=\sup_{h\ne 0}\frac{T(h)}{|h|}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{T(h)}{|h|}=\inf_{g\in \mathscr F} {\rm Var}(g).\tag{8}$$
3. If $V<+\infty$, then there exists a unique right(or left) continuous function $g\in  \mathscr F$; moreover, for this particular $g$, ${\rm Var}(g)=V$.

Comment: It seems sound to me. I'll discuss it with my classmates. There are two key steps. The first is reduction to Lebesgue points. The second is using approx. to id as test functions.

Comment: @FrankScience: In my argument, $E$ does not have to be the collection of Lebesgue points. I only need two requirements for $E$: (i) $E$ has full measure; (ii) $f_\epsilon$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $E$. Suppose I don't know almost every point is a Lebesgue point $f$, or I don't know $f_\epsilon(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ for every Lebesgue point $x$ of $f$. Then from $f_\epsilon$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$ we know that it has a subsequence convergent to $f$ pointwise on $E$ for some $E$ of full measure, so my argument still works, and in fact, that is my original thought.

Comment: @FrankScience: It turns out that you point is right and mine is wrong: reduction to Lebesgue points(slightly different to the usual definition) can simplify the proof essentially.

Comment: @FrankScience: Never mind.

Comment: Incidentally, could you write out your original proof which makes use of approximations to identity for reference or historic reasons?